# T-test on each row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe in which I am trying to apply T-test on each row but its giving me nan.

Code:

```
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, ttest_rel
import pandas as pd

df_stat = df_stat[['day', 'hour', 'CallerObjectId', 'signals_normalized', 'presence_normalized']]

def ttest(a, b):
    t = ttest_ind(a, b)
    return t

df_stat['ttest'] = df_stat.apply(lambda row: ttest(row['presence_normalized'], row['signals_normalized']), axis=1)
print(df_stat)
```

Output:

```
            day  hour                        CallerObjectId  signals_normalized  presence_normalized       ttest
0    2021-04-04     9  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            0.062500             0.514461  (nan, nan)
1    2021-04-04    16  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            0.187500             1.000000  (nan, nan)
2    2021-04-04    17  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            0.187500             0.895121  (nan, nan)
3    2021-04-04    18  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            0.062500             0.608823  (nan, nan)
4    2021-04-04    19  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            1.000000             0.716623  (nan, nan)
5    2021-04-04    20  287b19b7-32ce-4617-94b1-57a632f6f147            0.062500             0.314928  (nan, nan)
```

Comment: Because you have only 1 sample per population and their variance is `nan` with `ddof=1` to begin with...

Comment: `stats.ttest_ind(df.presence_normalized, df.signals_normalized)`

Answer (score 1):

A T-test is done to compare two *distributions*, you're using it to compare two *single values*.

Internally, a T-test divides by the variances of the distributions, the variance of a single sample is 0. So by doing a T-test on two individual values, you're dividing by zero. (See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Equal_sample_sizes_and_variance))

The values you're doing a T-test on appear to be aggregated per hour, you should probably do a T-test on the values without aggregating them per hour. Or you could do a T-test on each day for of your current values.